# If conditions for parameters in Ansible

Tags: if-statement, ansible, conditional-statements, logrotate

This is task to add cronjob to crontab:

```
    - name: Add job triggering logs rotation for clusters.
      cron:
        cron_file: '/etc/crontab'
        user: 'root'
        name: 'logrotate'
        minute: *
        hour: '*/4'
        job: '/etc/cron.daily/logrotate'
        state: present
```

What I want to accomplish is to add `minute: */5` and `hour: *` if `dev` in `inventory_hostname`, else add `minute: 0` and `hour: */4`.

Is there any way to do this adding conditions in minute and hour parameters? 
Can I deal with this using template, but just to add this two parameters in mentioned task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to achieve this with the [`ternary`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) filter:

```
    - name: Add job triggering logs rotation for clusters.
      vars:
        is_dev: "{{ 'dev' in inventory_hostname }}"
      cron:
        cron_file: '/etc/crontab'
        user: 'root'
        name: 'logrotate'
        minute: "{{ is_dev | ternary('*/5', '*') }}"
        hour: "{{ (is_dev | ternary('*', '*/4' }}"
        job: '/etc/cron.daily/logrotate'
        state: present
```

Comment: Haven't heard about this filter, but works perfect in this case! Much better than playing with templates. Thank you very much!

Comment: As said, this is one way to handle. This will not scale easilly fit you have a lot of params, for a lot of modules. In this case, putting the params in your inventory and splitting them by host/groups, still counting on a default, might be a much better option.